# why can I only present my first section in TableView Swift ?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created two arrays called section one and two to feed in their data to my table.

```
let Sec1 = ["Section" , "One"]
let Sec2 = ["Section", "Two"]
```

And I have create an array called `sectionTitles` which contains the name of my sections.

```
let sectionTitles = ["Section1" , "Sectoin2"]
```

And then I have the following delegate table view functions :

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{
    return sectionTitles[section]

    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        switch section {
        case 0 :
            return Sec1.count
        default:
            return Sec2.count

        }

    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = challengeTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID) as! CustomisedCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            cell.CAChallengeTitle.text = Sec1[indexPath.row]
            cell.CAChallengeDescription.text = "\(Sec1[indexPath.row])  "
            cell.CAChallengeButt.tag = indexPath[1]
            cell.CAChallengeButt.setTitle("I am interested >", for: .normal)
            print("Done with sectoin 0")
        default:
            cell.CAChallengeTitle.text = Sec2[indexPath.row]
            cell.CAChallengeDescription.text = "\(Sec2[indexPath.row])  "
            cell.CAChallengeButt.tag = indexPath[1]
            cell.CAChallengeButt.setTitle("I am interested >", for: .normal)
            print("Done with sectoin 1")

        }
       return cell

    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        let height : CGFloat  = 60
        return height
    }
```

But in the end I only get to present the fist section only. Any idea where am I making my mistake ? [image]

Comment: where is your `numberOfSections` method?

Comment: FYI - if all of your rows have the same height, do not implement `heightForRowAt`. Instead, set the `rowHeight` property of the table view. Do this in your storyboard or in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't implemented the `numberOfSections` data source method.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionTitles.count
}
```

Without this, the table assumes 1 section.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement numberOfRowsInSection method of tableView
in case you are using only static sactions then you have to return the count of sections in numberOfRowsInSection method. otherwise, store all the sections in an array and return 
`Array.count`

Comment: This is wrong. This is the `numberOfRowsInSection` method. The OP already has one of these and it is already correct. Please see the accepted answer for the correct solution.